# PDF rendition on Sharepoint

Tags: pdf, sharepoint-2007

I'm currently running a SharePoint 2007. The documents in my libraries will get a PDF rendition when they are approved.

Is there a way to show the PDF rendition in stead of the file when browsing the libraries. Users should be able to edit these files when selecting edit from the context menu.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate. You want to see PDF files only and when selecting 'edit' from the context menu then you want to edit the PDF file or the original (office?) source file? Disclaimer, I work for the makers of the Muhimbi PDF Converter for SharePoint :-) - http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft

We sell a SharePoint solution (Vizit) that has PDF rendition and annotation capabilities: http://www.atalasoft.com/products/vizit

There is no support for doing this in SharePoint alone unless you implement a solution.  You'd need to turn PDF into something web-browser compatible, and then implement the editing features you need.

If you have Acrobat installed on clients, you may be able to do what you need by using their ActiveX controls.  The trick is getting the edits back into SharePoint and playing nice with version control, etc (Vizit does all of this for you).

If you just need reading, you can serve the PDF with an HTTP header called "Content-disposition" set to "inline" -- they will not be able to edit.